# python - property() in a Class use problem, setter shows TypeError

Tags: python, class, properties, typeerror, setter

I'm coding a pybite on codechalleng.es and totally run out of ideas.
Problem is as follows:
[task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiWVP.png)

I need to write a class that returns boolean True/False whether the promotion has expired or not.
It's tested by invoking a property getter promotion.expired (see tests at the very end)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

NOW = datetime.now()    # defined here for test compatilibity (time)

class Promo:
    """ docstring hehe"""

    def __init__(self, name, expires):
        self.name = name
        self.setpromo(expires)


    def checkpromo(self):
        return self.expired

    def setpromo(self, value):
        self.expired = value < datetime.now()

    expired = property(checkpromo, setpromo)


test_time = NOW + timedelta(days=1)

promotion_10 = Promo('promotion 10%', test_time)
```

Now it throws an error where i can't compare value in setter vs. datetime object. In my opinion as we pass test_time (a datetime object) into setter, it should be able to compare datetime vs. datetime - instead the program says it's a bool. Not sure how to proceed. Thank you for any insight.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/simple_property.py", line 24, in <module>
promotion_10 = Promo('promotion 10%', test_time)
  File "/tmp/simple_property.py", line 10, in __init__
self.setpromo(expires)
  File "/tmp/simple_property.py", line 17, in setpromo
self.expired = value < datetime.now()
  File "/tmp/simple_property.py", line 17, in setpromo
self.expired = value < datetime.now()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

tests that needs to pass:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import inspect

from simple_property import Promo, NOW


def test_promo_expired():
    past_time = NOW - timedelta(seconds=3)
    twitter_promo = Promo('twitter', past_time)
    assert twitter_promo.expired


def test_promo_not_expired():
    future_date = NOW + timedelta(days=1)
    newsletter_promo = Promo('newsletter', future_date)
    assert not newsletter_promo.expired


def test_uses_property():
    assert 'property' in inspect.getsource(Promo)
```

Comment: edit - fixed indentation + added comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the issue - it might be interesting to someone experiencing such setter/property() behaviour. (Please correct me if im not supposed to answer my own question/close the topic etc.)

In my example, the property **expired** has the same name as private attribute self.**expired**.

After changing the code to (just adding one underscore in self._expired - changing the name so it does not overlap with property() name):

```
def checkpromo(self):
    return self._expired

def setpromo(self, value):
    self._expired = value < datetime.now()
```

It's worked! thank you

EDIT - adding elegant decorator way of solving the task (provided as an answer once submitted my task to codechalleng.es)

```
from datetime import datetime

NOW = datetime.now()


class Promo:

    def __init__(self, name, expires=NOW):
        self.name = name
        self.expires = expires

    @property
    def expired(self):
        return datetime.now() > self.expires
```